# Paypal Express Checkout demo files NVP/SOAP Demo Samples

Tags: php, soap, paypal

Wonder if anyone have tried successfully the Paypal demo code`s ?

My self is trying to get the Express Checkout Flow into my custom php, and downloaded the NVP / SOAP Code Samples from https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/download?capability=checkOutWithPaypal&lang=PHP
After input of my sandbox account details, it works very well, in-fact just as hoped. But (always a but), it seems that this setting from paypal_config.php do not work as it should be:

```
//Set this constant USERACTION_FLAG = true to skip review page
define("USERACTION_FLAG", false);

//Based on the USERACTION_FLAG assign the page
if(USERACTION_FLAG){
    $page = 'return.php';
} else {    
    $page = 'review.php';
}
```

If you try to set that to true, when directing from Paypal, you just comes to an white page.

Anyone got this to work as it should do?
Since it`s an express checkout, there should`t be needed for another "review" page, just hit Pay, and done!

Tried to locate all functions in the files, but the $page string is not anywhere to be found else than config file.

Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: The $page value looks like a script that's on your side. You have to check, maybe you have an error there and thus the page is returning blank.

Comment: @MarkSkayff Thing is that these files are original Paypal files, un-edited from me at all. :-)

Comment: I see. So, maybe they have something (a path inclusion or something) that's failing. Have you checked your logs to see if you have some errors? By logs I mean, the Apache logs, or some error_log file, etc...